# i am trying to use nested loop to get the subcategory but i am ending in a error "Property [Category] does not exist on this collection instance"

Tags: php, laravel-7

i have defined the self relation as such in my Category model

```
 public function Category()
        {
            return $this->hasmany(Category::class);
        }
```

in my migration i have defined

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->String('Parent_id');
            $table->String('name');
            $table->String('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in my controller i am trying to get the value of category as

```
 return view('index')->with('cate',Category::all());
```

i am trying to apply nested loop to get through subcategory in my blade file as

```
 <div class="list-group list-group-collapse list-group-sm list-group-tree" id="list-group-men" data-children=".sub-men">
                           @foreach($cate as $cat) 
                            <div class="list-group-collapse sub-men">
                            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="{{$cat->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}<small class="text-muted">(100)</small>
                            </a>
                            
                        <div class="collapse show" id="{{$cat->id}}" data-parent="#list-group-men">
                                    <div class="list-group">
                                      @foreach($cate->Category as $sub)
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">{{$sub->name}} <small class="text-muted">(50)</small></a>
                                      @endforeach  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            
                        </div>
```

i am trying to apply nested loop so i can see the sub category of the parent category but i am running into the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing i was doing wrong was defining a self realtion which should be defined as

```
public function Category()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id','id');
        }
```

and in order to get the parent id i have to use

```
$category=Category::where('Parent_id','=','0')->get();
return view('index')->with('cate',$category);
```

instead of

```
return view('index')->with('cate',Category::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many things wrong in your code.

According to your migration, the foreign key is named `Parent_id`, so given that this name doesn't follow laravel conventions you need to specify the exact the name when defining the relationship. Also, given that the relation could return several children item, I'd recommend you to adapt the method name.

```
### Category.php

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'Parent_id');
}
```

So, when querying data do the following:

```
$categories = Category::with('children')->get();

return view('index')->with('categories', $categories);
```

As an addition: a child category would like to access its parent category, so you could define another method in the model.

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'Parent_id');
}
```

This way, you can get info of the category parent:

```
$child = Category::find($id);
$parent = $child->parent;
```